# :target pseudo-class not working properly in firefox

Tags: css, debugging, firefox, target, pseudo-class

I am making a page with a CSS lightbox-type effect using the :target pseudo-class. When you click on an image, a box pops up with info in it, and goes away again when you click anywhere.

It's working perfectly in Chrome and IE, but in firefox there is a weird bug where **the text in my lightbox div disappears when you move the mouse away from the box**. It's acting like a hover effect, where you can only see the text when you are hovering over it.

I hope that explanation made sense, please let me know if I was not clear.

My CSS is here:

```
.lightbox {
display: none;
position: absolute;
z-index: 8;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background: #fff; 
padding-left: 30px;
}

.lightbox:target {
/* Show lightbox when it is target */
display: block !important;
outline: none;
}
```

Let me know if you need more information.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pseudo-class target works on **id** elements, not **classes**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

> The :target pseudo-class represents the unique element, if any, with an id matching the fragment identifier of the URI of the document.

Try replacing your .lightbox with #lightbox in your CSS, and your HTML element should be `<div id="lightbox">`

```
#lightbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 8;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff; 
    padding-left: 30px;
}

#lightbox:target {
    /* Show lightbox when it is target */
    display: block !important;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I asked the duplicate question [here][1] and was pointed to this answer. Accordingly i changed my setup to use the ID Tag ( http://whateverworks.style ). What is weird is that it fixed the problem of the div disappearing, even when clicking the video player controls (i.e. seeking with playhead, pausing). what still is not working though is that clicking the fullscreen button of the video player hides the video but then makes it fullscreen. i wonder if this a FF bug or another mistake on my side?

  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616472/firefox-handling-css-target