# Firefox handling CSS ::target

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, html5-video

Working example: http://whateverworks.style/

I am using the css ::target "trick" (https://bitsofco.de/the-target-trick/) to hide and show a video lightbox, adapted from here https://codepen.io/gschier/pen/HCoqh . The video "src" itself inserted via jquery into the ID of the HTML Video tag, itself positioned in the lightbox, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".works a").click(function(event) {
    var a = $(this).data('localvideourl'); //getter
    $("#localvideo-player").attr("src", function() {
      return a;
    });

    $("#localvideo-player").load()
  });

  $('.lightbox').click(function(e) {
    $('#localvideo-player')[0].pause();
  });
});
```

This mechanism works fine, on Chrome, Safari etc. But not on Firefox, at least on OSX (dont have Windows, so couldnt try there). The Problem seems to be, that unlike the other browsers, Firefox on OSX seems to execute the CSS Hide trick, before it actually considers the clicking of the video elements controls. So what happens, if clicking i.e. Fullscreen is that it hides the .lightbox div and then executes the click on the player controls, so playing the hidden div in Fullscreen. Notice that showing / hiding the DIV is actually not done via JS but with CSS only, just the video url is inserted with jQuery.

How can i avoid FF to behave like this? I am at a loss here since it seems to be a Firefox only problem.

Comment: You're using jQuery anyway, so why not use that to toggle the display status of the video in the first place?

Comment: I could, thats true. I tried to avoid JS / jQuery at all, thats how this solution came about but i couldnt figure out a way to reuse one video div for different videos without JS. And loading a hidden video div for each video didnt seem to be desirable. 

Still, i would like to understand why FF, unlike the other browsers behaves differently in this example.

Comment: This same question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27031275/target-pseudo-class-not-working-properly-in-firefox. Works on ID's not classes. So ".lightbox" needs to be "#lightbox" instead. Means there can be only one per page, though.

Comment: thanks, didnt see that. flagged it as duplicate.